# Problem with move tool in Photoshop CS 5.5

Tags: macos, adobe-photoshop, adobe

I just switched from PC to Mac, and there's a problem with Photoshop on OS X: I can't move any layer with the Move tool. It doesn't display any error or dialog box but it simply won't do it. Whenever I drag a layer, it will move back to its original location. However, I can nudge it using the arrow keys.

Mac OS X Lion 10.7.2

Photoshop CS 5.5

Comment: I had the same problem. It turned out to be the app "Friendly for Facebook." A small app I recently downloaded from the App Store. As soon as I disabled it, I could again use the move tool as normal.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my Mac. The problem was iCopy app in the taskbar. I unchecked Capture Mouse Drags in the Preferences and problem was solved.

Comment: But I don't have iCopy installed. What category of preferences? Mouse?